# NSData to NSString conversion return nil

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, xcode8, nsdata

I get data from a server with

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

It looks like this:

```
2017-08-02 12:00:52.242397+0530 Trainer[608:107784] data=<0a0a2246 61696c65 6420746f 20526563 6f766572 20796f75 72207061 7373776f 72642c20 74727920 61676169 6e22>
```

Attempting to convert it to a string with one of the code below returns `nil`:

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
```

Comment: What you passed in data?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh a string from php server

Comment: Can you post it?

Comment: Are you getting data in string?

Comment: in Xcode `NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

Comment: i got data in string

Comment: Are you using to call a service? It seems that you get data from url

Comment: `2017-08-02 12:00:52.242397+0530 Trainer[608:107784] data=<0a0a2246 61696c65 6420746f 20526563 6f766572 20796f75 72207061 7373776f 72642c20 74727920 61676169 6e22>
2017-08-02 12:00:52.242561+0530 Trainer[608:107784] data String= '

Comment: @Nirmalsinh i got content in data but cant convert it

Comment: What is supposed to mean the data? All NSData can't be converted to NSString.

Comment: @Larme data is a variable type of NSData

Comment: @Larme data contain just a string from php server

Comment: this is my php code 'echo json_encode(" error!");`

Comment: What is the source of the data is it a file or url? etc

Comment: What makes you sure that it is UTF8 encoded? What is the result of `+stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`? If it is `nil`, what is `error`? Otherwise, what is `usedEncoding`?

Comment: The string is \n\n"Failed to Recover your password, try again". UTF8 or ASCII.

Comment: @Lucasware its from url

Comment: @Willeke i know that is the string.. but cant convert it

Comment: I tried your code and it works.

Comment: So you are trying to get the contents of a downloadable file on the internet or the source of a webpage as an NSString?

Comment: @Willeke I see the printed part. But since it seems to be an output of `NSLog()` it might not be the complete data.